# Merging an array of json objects using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I've got a python array of json objects that I instantiate simply by doing this:

```
results = []
```

I'm then doing an API call, and I assign the `api_results['a_results']` to my array as follows:

```
api_results = api_func(url, session)
if loop = 0:
     results.append(api_results['a_results']) #NB: The 'a_results' object here is an array of json 
else:
     results[0].append(api_results['a_results'])
objects
```

The first time this is called, everything works as expected:

```
[
   [
      {
         object 1
      },
      {
         object 2
      }
   ]
]
```

However, if a certain number of results aren't found, the logic loops round again and I wish to append new results to the old object. This is where I'm having my issues.

The next iteration, the object looks like this:

```
[
   [
      {
         old object 1
      },
      {
         old object 2
      },
      [
         {
            new object 3
         },
         {
            new object 4
         }
      ]
   ]
]
```

So the array gets appended after object 2 as opposed to the actual objects.

Is there a way I can solve this issue? Essentially, when the threshold isn't met, I want an array of the 4 objects, as opposed to an array of the original 2 objects and then a sub array with 2 new objects.

I really want to append the objects within the array as opposed to the array I guess

Comment: Try changing the else-statement to `records.append(api_results['a_results'])`.

Comment: That just results in the 3rd and 4th object being added as an array at a different level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've had some joy doing this:

```
if page == 0:
   results.append(api_results['a_results'])
   results = results[0]
else:
   for i in api_results['a_results']:
   results.append(i)
```

For each element in the second array, append the object (eg Object 3 and 4)

This gets rid of the unnecessary outer array object too.

This may not be the most efficient means of solving the problem though.